# Why does my box2d.js/canvas script run faster with firebug open?

Tags: javascript, firebug, box2d

Seems truly bizarre, and I can't seem to find any cause.

I'm running a little simulation with box2d.js, just a few boxes with joints to make a 'rope'.

Using firefox (version 3.6.13) it runs quite sluggishly, until I open up firebug(version 1.6.0), and then there is a vast speed increace (at a guess I'd say at least 2x).

If I completely disable the firebug addon and restart the browser it remains slow.

What could be causing this, and how can I get it to run that fast normally?

---

EDIT

As proof, here is a zip file: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0B5twGxOv6WCsOTU5NzVjZTEtNGY0ZS00ZjFiLTkwNDUtYTE3YjlmNmU2Zjhh&sort=name&layout=list&num=50

Got a friend with an older version of firebug and he couldn't reproduce.

---

EDIT 2

If I change my implementation to using raphael instead of canvas it no longer occurs, so I think this must be to do with canvas.

Answer (score 1):

That is bizarre! Do you have any `console.log` calls in your code? Without Firebug those will fail, perhaps causing the slow-down.

Comment: Also, it might use two or more checks to see if `console` exists and that `console` has a method `log` which could slow it down. So when `console` does exist, it flies right past those checks.

Comment: I always include this code in my js so if console does not exist (as in no Firebug, or using IE) calls to console.log don't error:


if (!console) { 
    var console = {log:function(){}}; 
}

Comment: Sadly that doesn't seem to be it. There are no errors in firefox's error log, and 'grep -R console' in the source it's using gives no hits.

Comment: What's even odder is that using Firebug is known to slow Firefox down (it disables some of the JS optimisations in order to allow debugging).